# Is this formula for calculating prime numbers suitable for $n^2$ digits? $f(x)=|\sin⁡(πx/P_1 )|+|\sin⁡(πx/P_2 )|+⋯+|\sin⁡(πx/P_n )|$

Tags: prime-numbers, factoring

Is this form useful for to  detecting prime numbers, or can it be discarded?

$f(x)= |\sin\frac{⁡\pi x}{P_1} |+|\sin⁡\frac{\pi x}{P_2} |+⋯+|\sin⁡\frac{\pi x}{P_n} | $

Here is an example:
$P_1=2; P_2=3$

$f(x)=|\sin⁡\frac{\pi x}{2} |+|\sin\frac{⁡\pi x}{3}|$

[image: P_1=2; P_2=3 example]

The result is two new prime numbers, $5 $ and $7$ for $ x ∈ N$  without inflection point.

With these numbers, the formula can be expanded to obtain the next results for $n^2$.

[image: next results for n^2]

The result is new prime numbers: $11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43$ for $x ∈ N$ without turning point.

This series can be continued infinitely to calculate prime numbers.

This is another description of the sieve of Eratosthenes.

Appendix:

With this formula, you can also factorise all the numbers $P ∈ N$ .

$\sin\frac{\pi P}{x} = 0$ for  $x∈N$

Example for $P =12$

[image: P=12 factorization]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What is your definition of "turning point"?

Comment: Your form only detects the prime numbers you first used to compute it, it would be useful if you had a close formula that does not depend on primes. Also you should check how a sine is computed, we already have useful factorisation algorithms

Comment: Your example of factorization for $P=12$ is a special case since $12$ is divisible by many small integers. I believe in general $\sin \left(\frac{\pi P}{x}\right)$ has many more non-integer value zeros than integer value zeros, so the difficulty would be to pick out the integer value zeros.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will try my best.